# How to focus on specific section when tableview is initialised

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have a question regarding the tableview in swift 3.

I would like to go to a specific section when the tableview is initialised. I'm creating a calendar application and want to go to to section of the next coming event. I've googled and found nothing regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like...

```
tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath, at: ScrollPosition, animated: Bool)
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614997-scrolltorow